# Can't figure out how to authenticate with JWT auth for DocuSign eSignature API from Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, docusignapi

I attempting to use the JWT oAuth method to authenticate with the DocuSign API to create a template.  I keep receiving the response "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app".  I'm not great with connecting with APIs and needs some guidance.  It works fine with the X-DocuSign-Authenticate method but DocuSign will not allow this for REST after March 2023. This is a DocuSign demo developer account.

I've tried the code below but keep getting the same error.

```
    function createTemplate() {


    var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById("FILEID");
    var changeorderEncode = Utilities.base64Encode(driveFile.getBlob().getBytes());

    const JWT = "MY_ACCESS_TOKEN";
    const url = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<accountid>/templates';


   

   var payload =
   {
     
      "envelopeTemplateDefinition": {
          "name": "TestTemplate5"
      },
        "documents": [
          {
            "documentBase64": changeorderEncode,
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "Change Order Test 5"
          }
        ],
      
      "emailSubject": "1234 Easy St Change Order",
      
   "recipients": {
    
    "signers": [
      {
        "name": "Recipient Name",
        "recipientId": "1",
         "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "tabLabel": "Signature2",
              "xPosition": "407",
              "yPosition": "650"
            },
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "tabLabel": "Signature",
              "xPosition": "140",
              "yPosition": "650"
            }
          ],
          "dateTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1", //notes
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "tabLabel": "date",
              "xPosition": "140",
              "yPosition": "715"
            },
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "tabLabel": "date",
              "xPosition": "407",
              "yPosition": "715"
            }
          ],
          "textTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "name": "Project Address",
              "value": "1234 Easy St, Roseville, CA 95678",
              "width": 55,
              "xPosition":"76",
              "yPosition":"159"
            }
           ],
          }
         }
        ]
      },
      "status": "created"
    };




   var options =
   {     
     "method" : "post",
     "headers": 
       {
        "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "assertion": JWT,
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
     "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
     "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
   Logger.log(response.getContentText());
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is slightly incorrect.

`account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token` is the endpoint you'd use to get a token. You would use
`demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/{{account_id}}/templates` to create a template

You can get your baseUrl from the userInfo endpoint. All of this information is available on the [JWT Authentication page](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/)

I also think your content-type should be `application/json` since you are sending a JSON (json.stringify(payload) converts it into a json)

I'll also add a link to the [API Reference](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/) which will allow you to get the correct endpoint and the payload schema for all endpoints